# Using Data in MongoDB through Pymongo(Python)

Tags: python, arrays, mongodb, pymongo

I am interested in but am ignorant to the best method of extracting quantitative data fast and efficiently that I have inserted into MongoDB.

I will explain my process. I used MongoDB to hold a variety of quantiative data that I inserted from multiple .log files.

Now that the information is inserted, I would like to extract certain data through queries, format it into an array, and display it in a form of a GUI (matplotlib).

I am confused on how to go about the best method of extracting the data. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are some good tutorials on using the python and mongodb such as this http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html
Also there is some more information on SO on matplotplib with mongodb such as this one [Mongodb data statistics visualization using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8559080/mongodb-data-statistics-visualization-using-matplotlib)
It's probably better to start trying some things and then asking specific questions on SO when you get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

- use the standard query API
- use Map-Reduce
- use the new MongoDB aggregation framework